# I am not able to get the view action in gmail when sending the email using Java's mail api

Tags: java, email, google-schemas

Sample code snippet

```
MimeBodyPart htmlpart = new MimeBodyPart();
             htmlpart.setContent("<h1>Sample</h1><p>This is a sample HTML part","text/html");
             MimeBodyPart scriptcontent = new MimeBodyPart();

            // scriptcontent.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/ld+json");
             scriptcontent.setContent(" <script type=\"application/ld+json\">{ \"@context\":\"http://schema.org\",\"@type\":\"EmailMessage\",\"description\":\"Check this out\",\"action\": { \"@type\": \"ViewAction\",\"url\":\"https://www.youtube.com/\" } } </script>","application/ld+json");

             Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
             mp.addBodyPart(htmlpart);
             mp.addBodyPart(scriptcontent);

             mail.setContent(mp);
```

I have set the script type as json+ld , still i receive a normal email with no view action .

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the script tag string to the htmlpart? I'm not familiar with that API, but it seems like the script tag should be part of the HTML body part, not a separate part.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
MimeBodyPart htmlpart = new MimeBodyPart();
String html = "<html><h1>Sample</h1><p>This is a sample HTML part";
html += " <script type=\"application/ld+json\">{ \"@context\":\"http://schema.org\",\"@type\":\"EmailMessage\",\"description\":\"Check this out\",\"action\": { \"@type\": \"ViewAction\",\"url\":\"https://www.youtube.com/\" } } </script>";
html += "</html>";
htmlpart.setContent(html, "text/html");

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(htmlpart);

mail.setContent(mp);
```

Comment: Tried the code snippet , it didn't work . i read somewhere the mails need to be digitally signed with DKIM or SPF even when we are mailing ourself's . probably that should make it work . not sure though .